# JavaScript logic error

Tags: javascript, html-table

I am trying to get JavaScript to generate a table with data from an array for me however when I run this code it enters the same data twice. Does anyone know what mistake I am making?

The HTML:

```
<body>
<div class="container">
    <h1 class="page-header">Bookings</h1>
    <table id="bookTable" class="table table-bordered">
        <thead>
            <tr>
            <th>First Name</th>
            <th>Second Name</th>
            <th>Email</th>
            <th>From</th>
            <th>To</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td type="text" id="firstName"></td>
            <td type="text" id="secondName"></td>
            <td type="text" id="email"></td>
            <td type="text"id="dateFrom"></td>
            <td type="text"id="dateTo"></td>
        </tr>
    </thead>
  </table>
</div>
```

The JavaScript is using a guide I found that I have adapted. In reality, the array comes from a python file that is fed in as a variable when Flask displays the template. I have used the same data that python prints out when looking at the contents of the variable that is passed.

```
<script>
    var listOfBookings = [John`Doe`jd@gmail.com`03/01/2018`18/01/2018`John`Doe`jd@gmail.com`26/12/2017`27/12/2017]
    var array = listOfBookings.split("`");
    var count = 1
    for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++){
        if (1%(i+1) == 0){
            var firstName = array[i];
            }
        if (2%(i+1) == 0){
            var secondName = array[i];
            }
        if (3%(i+1) == 0){
            var email = array[i];
            }
        if (4%(i+1) == 0){
            var dateFrom = array[i];
            }
        if (5%(i+1) == 0){
            var dateTo = array[i];
            }



        // Addapted from http://talkerscode.com/webtricks/add-edit-and-
delete-rows-from-table-dynamically-using-javascript.php
        if(count%5 == 0){
            var table=document.getElementById("bookTable");
            var table_len=(table.rows.length)-1;
            var row = table.insertRow(table_len).outerHTML="<tr 
id='row"+table_len+"'><td id='date_row"+table_len+"'>"+firstName+"</td><td 
id='name_row"+table_len+"'>"+secondName+"</td><td 
id='country_row"+table_len+"'>"+email+"</td><td 
id='country_row"+table_len+"'>"+dateFrom+"</td><td 
id='country_row"+table_len+"'>"+dateTo+"</td></tr>";
        }
        count += 1
    }
</script>
```

Comment: `var listOfBookings = [John'Doe'jd@gmail.com'03/01/2018'18/01/2018'John'Doe'jd@gmail.com'26/12/2017'27/12/2017]'` this looks all sorts of invalid, even after fixing the quotes.

Comment: Also you a have multi-line string inside your `if(count%5 == 0)`, that won't work with quotes. use backticks or concatenate each line (or put it on one line, like on http://talkerscode.com/webtricks/add-edit-and-
delete-rows-from-table-dynamically-using-javascript.php)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code seems overly complicated. Here's a working example of how you might do it: (Note: I've added a `tbody` to your table, rather than have all these rows inserted into the `thead`)

```js
var listOfBookings = "John`Doe`jd@gmail.com`03/01/2018`18/01/2018`John`Doe`jd@gmail.com`26/12/2017`27/12/2017";
var array = listOfBookings.split("`");
var count = 1;
var table = document.getElementById("bookTable").getElementsByTagName('tbody')[0];
var row = table.insertRow(-1); //appends initial row  
row.id = "row_" + (count)
for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
  if (i % 5 == 0 && i > 0) {
    row = table.insertRow(-1); //appends a row
    row.id = "row_" + (++count)
  }
  var cell = row.insertCell(-1); //appends a cell
  var text = document.createTextNode(array[i]); //create the textNode
  cell.appendChild(text); //fill the cell with the text
  //(you could also set the cell id and other attributes at this point too)
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <h1 class="page-header">Bookings</h1>
  <table id="bookTable" class="table table-bordered">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>First Name</th>
        <th>Second Name</th>
        <th>Email</th>
        <th>From</th>
        <th>To</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your array seems to have `10` values and from all your `if` statements none of them will have their condition equal `true` when `i` is bigger then `4`.

All the variables (`firstName`, `secondName`, `email`, `dataFrom`, `dateTo`) will have the same value when `count` is `10` as they had when it was `5`

You could do something like this:

```js
    
var array = ["John","Doe","jd@gmail.com","03/01/2018","18/01/2018","John","Doe","jd@gmail.com","26/12/2017","27/12/2017"];
var table=document.getElementById("bookTable");
            
for (var i = 0; array.length % 5 === 0 && i < array.length;){
     var firstName = array[i++];
     var secondName = array[i++];
     var email = array[i++];
     var dateFrom = array[i++];
     var dateTo = array[i++];
     var table_len = (table.rows.length)-1;
     var row = table.insertRow(table_len).outerHTML="<tr id='row"+table_len+"'><td id='date_row"+table_len+"'>"+firstName+"</td><td id='name_row"+table_len+"'>"+secondName+"</td><td id='country_row"+table_len+"'>"+email+"</td><td id='country_row"+table_len+"'>"+dateFrom+"</td><td id='country_row"+table_len+"'>"+dateTo+"</td></tr>";
    }
```

```html
<body>
<div class="container">
    <h1 class="page-header">Bookings</h1>
    <table id="bookTable" class="table table-bordered">
        <thead>
            <tr>
            <th>First Name</th>
            <th>Second Name</th>
            <th>Email</th>
            <th>From</th>
            <th>To</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td type="text" id="firstName"></td>
            <td type="text" id="secondName"></td>
            <td type="text" id="email"></td>
            <td type="text"id="dateFrom"></td>
            <td type="text"id="dateTo"></td>
        </tr>
    </thead>
  </table>
</div>
```